# When executing stored procedure that return the count of "resident" in a table, expecting 4, but got zero instead

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have four rows in my `tblResident` table, where the `ID` column is the primary key, when I execute the following code, I was expecting to get  `4` back, but I got `0` instead. Why is this happening?

```
create procedure spGetTotalResidentCount2
as
begin
    return select count(ID) from tblResident
end

declare @TotalResident int 
execute @TotalResident =  spGetTotalResidentCount2
select @TotalResident
```

Comment: You will need to return count as OUTPUT parameter if you want to assign its value in @TotalResident field.

Comment: thank you all for the helpful comments and tips. But the thing is, i'm currently learning the concept of "return value" vs "output parameter", I think the syntax I have used in the example is of "return value", but I'm getting the wrong results, so just wondering why this is happening and how to fix it. Thanks again for all your help!!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
create procedure spGetTotalResidentCount2 as
begin
    set nocount on
    select count(ID) from tblResident
end

execute spGetTotalResidentCount2
```

**OR you could make a function :**

```
create function dbo.fnGetTotalResidentCount2 returns int as
begin
     declare @count int
     select @count = count(ID) from tblResident
     return @count
end
```

and use it like this

```
declare @count int
select @count = dbo.fnGetTotalResidentCount2
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use **OUTPUT** value in order to assign value to `@TotalResident` field.

```
create procedure spGetTotalResidentCount2
(
    @countResident int out
)
as
begin
    set @countResident = 4
end

declare @TotalResident int = 0
execute spGetTotalResidentCount2  @TotalResident out
select @TotalResident
```

OR You can do it with **RETURN** as well. Check the below code:

```
alter procedure spGetTotalResidentCount2
as
begin
    return 4
end

declare @TotalResident int = 0
execute @TotalResident = spGetTotalResidentCount2  
select @TotalResident
```

Answer (score 2):

Use OUTPUT clause

```
create procedure spGetTotalResidentCount2
@count int OUTPUT
as
    select @count = count(ID) from tblResident

return
GO

declare @TotalResident int 
execute @TotalResident =  spGetTotalResidentCount2 output
select @TotalResident
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are returning the values instead of just selecting them. Change the body of your procedure to just `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM tblResident`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC spGetTotalResidentCount2
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count INT;
  SELECT @count = count(ID) FROM tblResident;
  RETURN @count;
END
```